# How to use or in Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

How can use I use or in Query?

I want to return if name ="Michael" or age =21.
that is what I have

```
$d[contains((name,"Michael") or (age,"21"))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if they are = :

```
 $d[name = "Michael" or age = "21"]
```

or if you actually want to use contains:

```
 $d[contains(name,"Michael") or contains(age,"21")]
```

When you write `contains((,) or (,) )` you are seemingly using `or` on a syntactical level, giving two different  to the xquery parser. That is not possible in Xquery, or generally most programming languages, since their functions and operands operate on the *values* of the expressions, not on their *syntax*. `(name,"Michael")` however has no value (well, it has the value of a two element sequence, but that is not the value you are interested in), only `contains(name,"Michael")` has the actual value, of the test, if `name` contains `"Michael"`. So the or has to be between two calls to `contains`.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error "contains": function with arity 1 not declared

Comment: Here is my contains code $d[contains((name,"Michael") or contains(age,"21"))]

Comment: because you are still using ((, instead of a single (